# How to fix problem due to providing '@ionic-native/AppVersion' or '.../ngx' and having exception when calling any methods of AppVersion?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-plugins

I've added the AppVersion Ionic native plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version#usage). 
After try to provide it into my `app.module.ts` i've an error at compilation like "No provider exists for AppVersion" ...

I thinking that maybe from Ionic 4/recent version of AppVersion, i need to follow this instructions : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module which say to provide the plugin into the `app.module.ts` with a import like this :

`import AppVersion from '@ionic-native/AppVersion/ngx'`.

The code compile. Perfect. But sadly at runtime i have an error which say:

`TypeError: Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core__["cordova"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core__["cordova"])(this, "getPackageName", {}, arguments)', 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core__["cordova"])' is an instance of Object)
getPackageName — index.js:28...`

So my solution to this time-consuming problem, was to take an hold version of the AppVersion, which works on another project :

`package.json` :

```
...
"@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.18.0",
...
"cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
...
```

With this, i can import normally the plugin into my `app.module.ts` (`import AppVersion from '@ionic-native/AppVersion'`) and everything is ok.

There is the versions of my stack :

**Ionic:**

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

**Cordova:**

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 8 other plugins)

**System:**

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/maximedesogus/Library/Android/sdk/)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Answer (score 6):

Downgrade your current App version plugin, to do that remove this plugin first after that install this plugin again like::

```
1) ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version 

2) npm i @ionic-native/app-version@4.8.0
```

Comment: Thanks dude. For those finding this same answer, if you're using Ionic v3, make sure you follow the installation instructions found in the v3 docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-version/. They specifically state to install using `npm install --save @ionic-native/app-version@4`.